# SP Data dictionary

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created 1 procedure in my oracle database

```
create or replace procedure P1(p_empno in number)
is
p_ename varchar2(10);
p_sal number(10);
begin
select ename,sal into p_ename,p_sal from emp where empno=p_empno;
dbms_output.put_line(p_ename||'  '||p_sal);
end;

SQL> Procedure created.
```

But when i am trying to see the data dictionary then it looks like

SQL> select name from user_source;

```
NAME
------------------------------
P1
P1
P1
P1
P1
P1
P1
P1
PROTECTED_PROC
PROTECTED_PROC
PROTECTED_PROC
PROTECTED_PROC
PROTECTED_PROC
PROTECTED_PROC

14 rows selected.
```

what is this  I have created one time but it showing P1( 8 )times

Comment: [As documented in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-FD480C9E-F8DB-40DF-A04D-65765C45EA2F.htm#REFRN20249) `user_source` contains one row for each line in the procedure. Run `select name, line, text from user_source` and you will see

Comment: Maybe you want `select * from user_procedure where object_name = 'P1'`?

Answer (score 1):

`USER_SOURCE` table keeps source code of your procedure - one line per row. As your procedure is 8 lines long, you are getting 8 rows for each line of code (of your procedure).

It will be clear for you if query

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SOURCE WHERE WHERE NAME = 'P1';
```

or if you don't need source code query :

```
SELECT * FROM USER_PROCEDURES WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'P1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is 8 lines.

You can see with;

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SOURCE;
```